# YouTube Embed Javascript API showing a duration of 0 in onPlayerReady

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

The code below is not working in Internet Explorer for the YouTube embed javascript API.  That getDuration() shows 0?  This is working in Chrome and Firefox. Are there any reported bugs or fixes for this?  It as if it gets called but no parameters are initialized for the video.

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    self.videoDuration = event.target.getDuration();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So I wasnt saving a reference to the player which worked fine before. Once I added the variable below it started working.

```
var player;
function loadPlayer(startTime, endTime) {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {

...


}
```

This was still happening so I added a double check in this method.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

            if (self.videoDuration == 0)
                self.videoDuration = event.target.getDuration();
        }
    }
```